# python dict. if statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can someone assist me on the proper placement of an if statement on my dict. I am try to flag any user that is NY and have them come first in the dictionary.  I am able to get sort by name which I require as well but not clear how to flag any NY users

```
names_states = {
  'user1': 'CA',
  'user2': 'NY',
  'user7': 'CA',
  'guest': 'MN',
}


for key in sorted(names_states.iterkeys()):
   2   ...   print "%s :  %s" %(key, names_states[key])
   3   ...
   4   user1 :  CA
   5   user2 :  NY
   6   guest :  MN
   7   user7 :  CA
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sorted(names_states.iteritems(), key=lambda x: (x[1] != 'NY', x[0]))
```

Comment: Nice. This is just like mine, but inline with a lambda.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach that first pushes the NY values to the top, while still sorting by user name as the first key, and the state as the secondary key:

```
{'bill': 'NY',
 'frank': 'NY',
 'guest': 'MN',
 'user1': 'CA',
 'user2': 'NY',
 'user7': 'CA'}

def keyFunc(x):
    if names_states[x] == 'NY': 
        return (False, x)
    return (x, names_states[x])

sorted(names_states.iterkeys(), key=keyFunc)

# ['bill', 'frank', 'user2', 'guest', 'user1', 'user7']
```

Note: Sticking with the `key` approach here is faster than defining a custom `cmp` function. The key function will only be run once for each item, whereas a cmp function will be run every single combination.

Comment: `cmp` isn't run for _every_ combination. Just for each comparison the sort algorithm needs to make. Using `key` is far superior though

Comment: @gnibbler: My mistake. Thanks for clarifying. But ya, cmp still isn't as efficient.

Answer (score 2):

This does what you asked for-- All of newyorkers first, sorted by name, and then everyone else sorted by name too.

```
names_states = {
    'user1': 'CA',
    'user2': 'NY',
    'user7': 'CA',
    'guest': 'MN',
}

def ny_compare(x, y):
    if names_states[x] == 'NY':
        if names_states[y] == 'NY':
            return cmp(x,y)
        else:
            return -1
    elif names_states[y] == 'NY':
        return 1
    return cmp(x,y)


for key in sorted(names_states.iterkeys(), cmp=ny_compare):
    print "%s :  %s" %(key, names_states[key])
```

Comment: You could shorten those if-else blocks by just returning `return cmp(x,y)`

Comment: No prob. Ya its much nicer now ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Using tuple unpacking may make it clearer

```
sorted(names_states.iteritems(), key=lambda (name, state): (state != 'NY', name))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, value in sorted(names_states.iteritems(), 
            key=lambda (key, value): ((0 if value == 'NY' else 1), key)):
    print((key,value))
```

Here iteritems() gets us an iterator over the key/value pairs in the dictionary. We can then sort those key/value pairs. The lambda expression creates a set of keys that will sort the list as you say. It does this by returning tuples, whose first element is a number based on whether the value is `'NY'` or not. Basically, I'm using the fact that tuples are sorted by their first element and then their second and so on.

That said, this is beginning to look quite messy, so you may want to find a more verbose, but clearer way to do this.

You may wish to subclass dict and add an additional method that exposes the keys, values or key/value pairs in the order you desire.

That way you can have something as simple as:

```
names_states = MyDict({
  'user1': 'CA',
  'user2': 'NY',
  'user7': 'CA',
  'guest': 'MN',
})

for key, value in names_states.iteritems_with_given_values_first('NY'):
    ...

class MyDict(dict):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def iteritems_with_given_values_first(self, preferred_value):
        for key, value in sorted(names_states.iteritems(), 
                key=lambda (key, value): ((0 if value == preferred_value else 1), key)):
            yield key, value
```